# How can I parse this set of data from a log file which is always in the same format

Tags: python

Okay so I am trying to parse through a log file and extract certain info. Firstly I would like to split the individual errors into a list and I would also like to essentially create a table of the error Date, Time, Error Code, and Cycles

Here is a sample of data from my error log file

```
ERROR
: 05/06/2021 02:47  
Al      N.A.C.
Al      20851 
_ERR = Bad Video
Al      445014      R 0        T 10000  Z 0 
ERROR
: 05/06/2021 02:52  
Al      N.A.C.
Al      20851 
_ERR = Bad Video
Al      445230      R 0        T 13000  Z 0 
ERROR
: 05/06/2021 05:16  
Al      N.A.C.
Al      20851 
_ERR = Bad Video
Al      445508      R 0        T 14000  Z 0
```

NOTE: Data in my log file is always formatted in this way

for example the individual error list would have 3 errors or items in it for this set of data.

where the first index would be:

```
ERROR
: 05/06/2021 02:47  
Al      N.A.C.
Al      20851 
_ERR = Bad Video
Al      445014      R 0        T 10000  Z 0
```

doesn't have to include the first line "ERROR" necessarily.

Then I would go through each index in that list of errors and parse out into a table as follows:

```
INDEX DATE      TIME   CODE   CYCLES
1     5/06/2021 02:47  20851  445014
2     5/06/2021 02:52  20851  445230
3     5/06/2021 05:16  20851  445508
```

and then I could use this of course to plot my data.

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: I tried using the with open and readlines, but that just separates each line into each element of the list. I also tried doing a split for the "ERROR" substring but that is also for individual strings couldn't separate multiple lines at once with it.

Comment: You could loop through each row, building a list of each entry. When you hit 'ERROR', save that list in another list and start again. Else you could do your error split and firther split on '\n' (new line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally without error checking so use at your own risk.

```py
from io import StringIO
import sys, csv

data = '''\
ERROR
: 05/06/2021 02:47  
Al      N.A.C.
Al      20851 
_ERR = Bad Video
Al      445014      R 0        T 10000  Z 0 
ERROR
: 05/06/2021 02:52  
Al      N.A.C.
Al      20851 
_ERR = Bad Video
Al      445230      R 0        T 13000  Z 0 
ERROR
: 05/06/2021 05:16  
Al      N.A.C.
Al      20851 
_ERR = Bad Video
Al      445508      R 0        T 14000  Z 0 
'''

rows = []
f = StringIO(data)  # replace f with your input file
for line in f:
    if line == 'ERROR\n':
        rows.append([])  # start a new list
        line = next(f)
        rows[-1].extend(line.split()[1:3])
        next(f)  # skip N.A.C. line
        line = next(f)
        rows[-1].append(line.split()[1])
        next(f)  # skip _ERR line
        line = next(f)
        rows[-1].append(line.split()[1])

HEADERS = 'INDEX DATE      TIME   CODE   CYCLES'.split()
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)  # replace sys.stdout with your output file
writer.writerow(HEADERS)

for i, values in enumerate(rows, start=1):
    writer.writerow([i] + values)
```

Comment: You are the best! This worked perfectly! Now I can write this out to a CSV file and plot from there etc.